# In windows, Why the handle value is in multiple of 4?

Tags: windows, process, sysinternals

If I'm not wrong, A handle is an index inside a table maintained on per process basis.

For 64bit Windows, Each entry in this table is made up of 8 byte address to the kernel object + 4 byte of access mask making the entry 12 byte long. However as I understood, for alignment purpose each entry made 16 byte long.

But when you you look at handle opened by a process using process explorer, Value of handle are in multiple of 4. Shouldn't this be in multiple of 16 instead?

[image: process explorer screen shot]

Comment: [Why are kernel HANDLEs always a multiple of four?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050121-00/?p=36633)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Windows handle is just an index per se, it could be a multiple of 1 in principle. It has been probably more efficient to implent a word (16 bit value) alignment than the byte alignment you're implying.

Answer (score 1):

The lowest two bits of a kernel handle are called "tag bits" and are available for application use. This has nothing to do with the size of an entry in the handle table.

The comment in `ntdef.h` (in `Include\10.0.x.x\shared`) says:

```cpp
//
// Low order two bits of a handle are ignored by the system and available
// for use by application code as tag bits.  The remaining bits are opaque
// and used to store a serial number and table index.
//

#define OBJ_HANDLE_TAGBITS  0x00000003L
```

My guess is that it's a similar misuse like using the most significant bit of 32 bit pointers as a boolean flag, which is why we have LAA (large address aware) and non-LAA applications.

You could (but should not) add 1, 2 or 3 to a HANDLE and it should not affect other Windows API methods. E.g. `WaitForSingleObject()`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    auto created = CreateProcess(L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
        nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, FALSE, 0, nullptr, nullptr, &si, &pi
    );
    if (created)
    {
        pi.hProcess = static_cast<byte*>(pi.hProcess) + 3;
        const auto result = WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
        if (result == 0)
            std::cout << "Completed!\n";
        else
            std::cout << "Failed!\n" << result << "\n";
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Not created";
}
```